# SQL - Extracting specific element name, attribute name and values

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

I have a table that holds an xml document that looks like the following. I want to extract the highlighted values as column values. I've looked at so many threds but I'm having a nightmare!

I'm OK getting the values i.e. 15 James' drive, but it's the rest i'm struggling with

Ideally I'd have a table like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible sample:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data from #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Also, who is your database vendor? I assumed that it is MS SQL Server.